# phpunit setup not picking up replacement version

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, pear

i'm trying to change phpunit version to 3.5 following this tutorial http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

the correct files seem to be installed but i get errors like these

root@gerard:/home/gerard/sites/zf# phpunit /var/www/tests/unittests.php

```
PHPUnit 3.7.24 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method RemoteConnectTest::hasPerformedExpectationsOnOutput() in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php on line 628
```

&&

root@gerard:/home/gerard/sites/zf# phpunit --version

```
PHPUnit 3.7.24 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

// shows wrong version

the proper files all seem to be installed at /usr/share/php/PHPUnit 
the version shown in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php is   'PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.'

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to update the phpunit binary PATH. You can check the path for this command by doing:

```
which phpunit
```

If it is pointing to the 3.7 folder, changing it to the 3.5 folder should resolve the issue.

If that doesn't work then remove both versions and reinstall 3.5 with all the correct dependencies. I have had similar issues in the past and it is much quicker to remove it and start from scratch.

Comment: something like that indeed. when i removed the 3.6 and installed the 3.5 the phpunit command point to the old file which still existed. the version is hardcoded in both that file and in framework/runner/version.php